# Instagram API review submission - complete app needed?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I just noticed that new Instagram API's sandbox has too many restrictions and I would need to submit review to build my app. I googled to see if there's a way around but looks like using their API would be better than anything.

The app I was going to build requires all the API endpoints that Instagram doesn't allow Sandbox users to access (such as hashtag search and get recent tags). Do I just build one assuming I can get responses from the endpoints? I am pretty confused. Anything would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think you have two options:

- Since, instagram allows you get the contents from the user's in the sandbox mode.
- Create an App using [link](http://instagram.com/developer/) and submit for review to get experience with public data available in instagram.